# I would like to make/have a scala like 'future' async API for python

Tags: python, scala, asynchronous

I needed a few futures to wait on others in Python/Django and I had to hack my own "Promise" class using sources off the net and concurrent.futures (backport to 2.7).

Here is my code (not pretty but works for exactly what I need), I got most of the idea from a blog post (and I cannot find the link to it now ... will update later):

```
class Promise(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        LOG.debug('Create Promise from callable %s %s' % (func, str(inspect.getargspec(func))))

    def resolve_on_type(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, Future):
            return self.resolve_on_type(arg.result()) # happens when chaining two promises.
        elif isinstance(arg, types.GeneratorType):
            iterable = list()
            for a in arg:
                iterable.append(self.resolve_on_type(a))
            return iterable
        else:
            return arg

    def resolve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        resolved_args = []
        resolved_kwargs = {}

        #TODO need a more efficient way to wait on all results
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            resolved_args.append(self.resolve_on_type(arg))

        for kw, arg in kwargs.items():
            resolved_kwargs[kw] = self.resolve_on_type(arg)

        try:
            return self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
        except:
            LOG.exception('<Promise> Error on task execution.')
            raise

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        LOG.debug('Promise %s called' % self.func)
        return thread_pool.submit(self.resolve, *args, **kwargs)
```

Personally I would like something a bit [more scala like](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

```
def my_function(some, args, here):
    #do stuff that takes time and blocks or whatever
    return something

future_1 = future(my_function, _some, _args, _here_please).map(mapping_function).recover(error_handling_function)
future_1.result()

list_of_futures = map(async_functions, some_args)
future_of_list = sequence(list_of_futures)
```

I would appreciate any hints ... or is there something out there that works well? I must say `concurrent.futures` has simplified my task but I have no idea how get `map` work. I think I need experts (I have been less than a couple months in active python development before that I used it for maintenance scripts on files and dbs).
I think if I get sequence and map I could get how to work the rest out for myself.

Comment: why can't use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) like task scheduling systems?

Comment: I want it to be self contained, without having to bother with workers or actors, or anyother wossnames,and without extra setup (except creating a ThreadPool instance) ... like I said "scala-like". Scala does not (at least not anymore) need Akka to do async.

Comment: Did you have a look at [the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/library/scala/concurrent)? There's all you need to know...

Comment: That is a very good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python’s *concurrent.futures* indeed do a poor job in enabling future composition and reactive programming.

Have a look at [this library](https://github.com/mikhtonyuk/rxpython), it implements Scala-like *Futures* and *Promises*. Implementation is small and well tested, and should be easy to port to Python 2.7 to suit your needs.

It wraps *concurrent.futures* *ThreadPoolExecutor* to return enhanced *Future* objects:

```
from rx.executors import ThreadPoolExecutor
from rx.futures import Future

with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as tp:
    futures = [tp.submit(foo, i) for i in range(10)] # list of futures
    future_all = Future.all(futures) # combines into single future with list of results
    future_all_sum = future_all.map(sum) # maps result list to sum of elements
    print(future_all_sum.result(timeout=10))
```

Comment: Is that library trying to do what RxJS, RxNET, and RxJava are doing?

Comment: It is modeled after Scala's futures, RxJava-like Observables are on the todo list.